# Recovering data from a lost/deleted HFS partition in Mac OS X

Tags: macos, partitioning, data-recovery, disk-utility, partition-recovery

I have a 2TB hard drive with 2 partitions. It got partition by a program into 5gb accidentally.

I tried using [Disk Drill Pro](http://www.cleverfiles.com/pro.html) to recover the lost partitions and it could see it but could not rebuild because of the existing 5GB. So, I deleted the 5GB partition with disk utility tried again with Disk Drill Pro and I could not see the lost partition to rebuild.

I used [TestDisk](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk) earlier to get the maps of each partition. I used [pdisk](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/pdisk.8.html)’s terminal and partitioned it to the maps provided by TestDisk. Now the first partition 1.8gb, won’t mount on disk utility!

What should I do? Are my files gone? Should I repair the catalog file with Disk Utility?

Here are the disk details
With the 5GB;

```
Partition map ( 2048 byte block ) on /dev/
#:                    type name           length   base       ( size )
1:     Apple_partition_map Apple              15 @ 1
2:               Apple_HFS disk image    2637456 @ 16         (  5.0G)
3:              Apple_Free                     3 @ 2637472 

Device block size=2048, Number of Blocks=2637475  ( 5.0G)
Device Type=0x0 DeviceId=0x0
```

After I deleted the 5GB using Disk Utility:

```
Partition map ( 512 byte block ) on /dev/rdisk2/

#:                    type name           length   base       ( size )
1:     Apple_partition_map Apple              63 @ 1
2:               Apple_Free.          3906363456 @ 64         (  1.8T)

Device block size=512, Number of Blocks=3906963456 (1.8T)
Device Type=0x0 DeviceId=0x0
```

After changing the map to TestDisk’s using pdisk

```
Partition map ( 512 byte block ) on /dev/rdisk2/

#:                    type name           length   base        ( size )
1:     Apple_partition_map Apple              63 @ 1
2:              Apple_Free Extra             448 @ 64
3:               Apple_HFS My         3882374848 @ 512         (  1.8T)
4:              Apple_Free              24588096 @ 3882375360  ( 11.7G)

Device block size=512, Number of Blocks=3906963456  (1.8T)
Device Type=0x0 DeviceId=0x0
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if/how to fix your FS, but [PhotoRec](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec) from the same author as TestDisk is quite good, in my experience, at recovering files. Maybe you should try and recover as much as possible before trying to fix it further?

Comment: This is **not** an answer to the original question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment).